# How to stop sql assistant?

Tags: teradata

I have run a query in teradata and sql assistant in `(Not Responding)`

I do not want to loose the query?

What can I do to stop it and keep the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open another instance of SQL Assistant and see if the query has been saved to the History.
2. Ask the DBA to abort your session on your behalf which should return control to SQL Assistant.
3. Ask the DBA if DBQL has been enabled and how you can retrieve the SQL from the query logs. (You may or may not have direct access to the logging tables.)